# What is the weather data covering the range of 359 to 360 degree

Tags: oceanography, ocean-currents

I downloaded a grib file of oceanography (Mean Wave Period) from ERA-Interim and the longitude values give the value at the points is 0,1, 2, 3....357, 358, 359

If I have geographical coordinates that fall between the range 359 to 360 degree longitude. How can I represent them?

Thank you for your time and concern reading my question,

Sincerely,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that 360° == 0°. They're the same line of longitude. So the gap between 359° and 0° is no more than the gap between 1° and 2°, and should be handled the same way.

Comment: Hi Simon, so the value at 359.25 should be the same as the value at 1.25 ?

Comment: @EwokTheSithLord no, the value at 359.25 is the same as the value at -0.75. Think of a line of equally spaced numbers through this region: 359.0, 359.25, 359.50, 359.75, 0.00, 0.25, 0.5.... does that help?

Comment: Hi Simon, sorry to bother you again. But as I mentioned if the range is only from 0 to 359, I cannot guess the value at 359.25 (since -0.75 is not in this range)

Comment: Remember that 360° is the same as 0°. You have information at 0°.

If you need to know the value at 7.5°, you will probably interpolate between the values at 7° and 8°. If you need to know the value at 359.5°, you can interpolate between the values at 359° and 0°. It's no different.

Comment: Thank you so much Simon, for the interpolation method, would you recommend cubic ?

Comment: That depends on your data, what you want to do with it, etc., so I'm not going to try to answer. But the point is that whatever method you would use between any other whole-degree angles, you can use between 359 and 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will duplicate the data at 359 and at 0 to interpret the range.